# MaterialSearchView + Toolbar + Map

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to integrate a search toolbar with google maps.
This is the relevant part:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.myapp.DrawerActivityMainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView>

        <include layout="@layout/activity_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And `activity_maps.xml`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.MapsActivity" />
```

The problem is the MaterialSearchView is showing **bellow** the map (i.e the map overlaps). How to integrate MaterialSearchView with Toolbar and Google map?

Comment: Did my answer worked in your case or not or do you facing any issues with using my answer !! ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `Relative Layout` to setup view `Below` and bind it with the `Frame Layout` as you already doing. Also change root layout to `Relative Layout` instead of `Linear Layout`.

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:label="MyApp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frameOne"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can view the output below as well it seems to be fix with this.

[image]

Comment: Did it worked for you ? !!! If you are facing issue with using this then let me know !!!!

Comment: @user3599803 It seems to be work because it is using layout_below property and as of the screen shot it is showing not overlapping toolbar. Did you updated layout correctly ?